# Can Homunculi Wield Weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, weapons

Say I want to equip my homunculus with a halberd. A homunculus' STR stat is 4, which means it can carry 30 pounds of weight. Since 4 x 15 is 60 lb. for base carrying capacity, divided by 2 for its Tiny size according to the PHB, and a halberd weighs 6 lb, a homunculus can at least *carry* a halberd without much issue. A halberd has the Heavy and Two-handed properties, which gives disadvantage to Small creatures and requires the use of two hands, respectively. Assuming the Heavy property also applies to Tiny creatures, does that mean that my homunculus can wield a halberd with two hands, with disadvantage, and without proficiency, since it's a martial weapon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Yes, but it will rarely hit anything.

You seem to have covered your bases on checking if it can wield the thing. I can’t come up with a reason why it wouldn’t be able to. However, it will rarely hit anything.

Without proficiency, a -3 STR modifier, and disadvantage on all attacks, your homunculus’s average attack roll is about 4 (7.175 - 3), and when it does hit, the damage will be a poor 1d10 - 3. At that point, you’re probably better off sticking with the Bite attack and trying to land a poison.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. Once the Help action is taken by a familiar, and if I ever manage to acquire Gauntlets of Ogre Power, that seems like a non-issue. Plus, weapons that have the Light property could be used, or weapons that lack the Heavy property.

Answer (score 6):

The only thing you haven't taken into account isn't a true rule per se, but it may impact things.

There is a note in the DMG on page 278, where it's talking about how to handle things if a player character decides to grab a weapon sized for a bigger creature, like a giant or minotaur:

> A creature has disadvantage on attack rolls with a weapon that is sized for a larger attacker. You can rule that a weapon sized for an attacker two or more sizes larger is too big for the creature to use at all.

Going by that, a tiny Homunculus can't use weapons sized for medium creatures, the same way a human can't use a huge giant's axe. It's an optional thing -- the DM *can* rule that way, but is not required to do so.

You could take the Light and Heavy qualities into account here, treating a light weapon sized for Medium as if it were a normal weapon sized for a Small creature (a ruling that has its basis as far back as *The Hobbit*), and thus usable by a tiny homunculus (with disadvantage, as it's still too large). I definitely wouldn't let a cat-sized creature swing a halberd around, no matter how strong it is, though. It would need a custom designed halberd intended for a Tiny creature.

Weapon size isn't just about weight, after all -- arguably, it's *more* about grip and balance than raw mass. For example, even if it were very light, you couldn't really use a sword with a handle six inches across; try swinging a cardboard tube of that diameter. It's awkward and tries to slide out of your grip every time you hit something!

Comment: And the length acts similarly: you could be as strong as an ox, if you're tiny and try to swing a 10 foot long halberd, it's more likely to be you who ends up flying.

Comment: Yeah, I consider lever arm to be an aspect of balance.